# Using sqlite3 as a dependency in globally installed Node project

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, installation, npm

I'm trying to install a Node project to my machine globally. It's using sqlite3 to query my itunes.db file. The package structure looks like:

```
/node_modules
db.js
index.js
itunes.js
package.json
```

I can properly run the application when I run from this local directory. I'm using the alias "itunes" to run the app.

```
C:\Users\Khalil\Documents\itunes-cmd\npm install -g
C:\Users\Khalil\Documents\itunes-cmd\itunes play shut me down

--- Multiple Songs Found -----
[0] - Shut Me Down - Rowland S. Howard - Teenage Snuff Film
[1] - Shut Me Down - Rowland S. Howard - Pop Crimes

Which song # you want to play [Enter #]: 1
Playing 'Shut Me Down' by Rowland S. Howard
```

But as I move out of the project directory, and try to run the app I get an error.

```
cd ..
cd ..

itunes play shut me down


C:\Users\Khalil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\itunes-cmd\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\trace
.js:28
                    throw err;
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Khalil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\itunes-cmd\index.js:120:22
    at C:\Users\Khalil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\itunes-cmd\db.js:132:11
    at Statement.errBack (C:\Users\Khalil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\itunes-cmd\node
_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js:16:21)
--> in Database#all('SELECT * FROM ITUNES_LIBRARY WHERE TITLE LIKE ? ', '%shut me down%',
[Function])
    at DatabaseController.findSongByTitle (C:\Users\Khalil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\itunes-cmd\db.js:131:8)
    at searchSong (C:\Users\Khalil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\itunes-cmd\index.js:11
6:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Khalil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\itunes-cmd\ind
ex.js:158:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
    at startup (node.js:118:18)
```

I've discovered that when I run the application, the result returned from findSongByTitle usually returns an array of song Objects but prints out undefined when I get the error.

```
 // Search database for song title
    db.findSongByTitle(searchQuery, function(result){
        console.log(result); // prints undefined

        // If only one result, play that song
        if(result.length == 1){
            playTrackFromLocation(result[0].LOCATION, result[0].TITLE, result[0].ARTIST);

        // Otherwise, ask the user which song they want to play (by number)
        } else {
            console.log("--- Multiple Songs Found -----");
            for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
                console.log(chalk.yellow("[" + i + "] - " + result[i].TITLE + " - " + result[i].ARTIST + " - " + result[i].ALBUM));
            }

            // Wait for user's response.
            console.log("");
            var songSelection = readlineSync.question('Which song # you want to play [Enter #]: ');

            if(!isNaN(songSelection)){
                // Play selected track
                console.log("");
                playTrackFromLocation(result[songSelection].LOCATION, result[songSelection].TITLE, result[songSelection].ARTIST);
            } else {
                console.log(chalk.red("No valid song # selected"));
            }
        }
    });
```

The findSongByTitle function looks like this:

```
DatabaseController.prototype.findSongByTitle = function(search, callback){
db.all("SELECT * FROM ITUNES_LIBRARY WHERE TITLE LIKE ? ", '%' + search + '%', function(err, queryResults) {
      callback(queryResults);
});
```

}

Totally not sure if I'm missing something obvious here or not, I just don't get why it doesn't work when my global installation path at:

```
C:\Users\Khalil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\itunes-cmd
```

has an exact copy of all of the locally installed files.
The rest of my code is here at [GitHub](https://github.com/stemmlerjs/iTunesController).

Comment: why not just install node modules locally then make add the entry point to your app in your PATH?

Comment: I want users to be able to just do:

    npm install itunes-cmd -g

Just like you would do to globally install npm modules regularly (like nodemon for example). 
That is something that's possible, right?

Comment: Also, it doesn't make sense that all of the **other modules** that I've required are somehow working but only sqlite3 isn't working properly.